# MySQL UPDATE CASE not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to make this query work but I'm unable to update the desired field. This is my code:

```
UPDATE inventory
SET inventoryCount = CASE 
 WHEN itemId = 1 THEN inventoryCount+1
 WHEN itemId = 2 THEN inventoryCount+3
 WHEN itemId = 3 THEN inventoryCount+6
 ELSE inventoryCount
 END
WHERE itemId IN (1,2,3) AND outletId = 23 AND companyId = 2
```

I need to add up `X` amount to the current amount in `inventoryCount`, some how it seems to ignore it and nothing changes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has syntax errors, so it's probably not even executing correctly;

```
WHEN itemId = 1 THEN inventoryCount+1,  <-- comma should not be there
WHEN itemId = 2 THEN inventoryCount+3,  <-- comma should not be there
WHEN itemId = 3 THEN inventoryCount+6,  <-- comma should not be there
```

If you remove the extra commas, the query will execute correctly;

[An SQLfiddle to show the working query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abe9e/1).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay, sorry those commas where added by mistake only when I posted here, my actual code doesn't have those commas. I updated my question

Comment: @CrashOverride Then [there is nothing wrong with your SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11edc9/1). Could you post some sample data that you would expect to be updated but that isn't?

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem, the thing is that I have a PHP script that creates the WHEN condition for every item though a loop, and it seems like MySQL doesn't allow you to update the same field with the same ID multiple times in the same query "using the previous syntax" But thanks for your help, it really helped me.